# warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am creating an app using parse and I got an warning saying `"A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug."` So I have placed an breakpoint in `warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread`. The app stopped at the breakpoint and pointed out item.fetchIfNeeded.  Why is this happening? I don't see anything wrong with my code. Any help is appreciated. Thank you !

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("loveView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoveCollectionViewCell
        let item = self.votes[indexPath.row]


        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("onDoubleTap:"))
        gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)


        // Display "initial" flag image
        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        cell.postsImageView.image = initialThumbnail

        // Display the country name
        if let user = item["uploader"] as? PFUser{
            item.fetchIfNeeded()
            cell.userName!.text = user.username


            var profileImgFile = user["profilePicture"] as! PFFile
            cell.profileImageView.file = profileImgFile
            cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground { image, error in
                if error == nil {
                    cell.profileImageView.image = image
                }
            }

            var sexInt = user["sex"] as? Int
            var sex: NSString!
            if sexInt == 0 {
                sex = "M"
            }else if sexInt == 1{
                sex = "F"
            }else{
                sex = " "
            }

            var height = user["height"] as? Int
            if height == nil{
                cell.heightSexLabel.text = " "
            }else{
                var nonOpHeight = height as Int!
                cell.heightSexLabel.text = "\(sex) \(nonOpHeight)cm"
            }


        }

        if let votesValue = item["votes"] as? Int
        {
            cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votesValue)"
        }

        // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
        if let value = item["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
            println("Value \(value)")
            cell.postsImageView.file = value
            cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    cell.postsImageView.image = image
                }
            })
        }

        //Adjusting the position of heart image
        cell.votesLabel!.sizeToFit()
        cell.votesLabel!.center = CGPointMake(cell.bottomBlurView.center.x - (cell.heartImage.frame.width / 2)-1.5, cell.bottomBlurView.frame.size.height / 2)
        cell.heartImage.frame.origin.x = cell.votesLabel!.frame.origin.x + cell.votesLabel!.frame.width + 1.5



        return cell
    }
```

Comment: How did you set the warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `fetcIfneeded` method will be execute on main thread, use `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock`  method instead. Inside block check if `success = true` then fetch file as well.