# Run Parse operations in background

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an app, that gets data from the Parse server. Below is the code I'm using to go through all of the rows in "Offer" class and store them inside offerList array. Everything is working as expected, but I keep getting

```
warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread()
```

warnings in Xcode. Calling the whole function or it's body inside

```
DispatchQueue.global().async
```

also doesn't help. Here's the actual func:

```
func parseOfferList(){
    var amount: Int = 0
    offerList.removeAll()
    let offerQuery = PFQuery(className: "Offer")
    offerQuery.countObjectsInBackground { (count, error) in
        if error == nil {
            amount = Int(count)

            for i in 1...amount-1{
                let offerObj = try! offerQuery.whereKey("ID", equalTo: i).getFirstObject()
                var tempOffer = Offer()
                tempOffer.id = offerObj.object(forKey: "ID") as! Int
                tempOffer.name = offerObj.object(forKey: "name") as! String
                tempOffer.desc = offerObj.object(forKey: "desc") as! String
                tempOffer.lowSale = offerObj.object(forKey: "lowSale") as! Int
                tempOffer.topSale = offerObj.object(forKey: "topSale") as! Int

            offerList.append(tempOffer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run this function right when the app starts, so when user logs in, offerList is already filled with info. Any ways to achieve this?

Comment: What code is executed after offerList.removeAll() or offerList.append(tempOffer)? Do you use didSet() { } ?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on `warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread()` and check the stack. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034690/warnblockingoperationonmainthread-error